# How do I get the words immediately before my regex condition?

Tags: c#, regex

RegEx to help me find :line in the stacktrace

```
\W*(:line)\W*
```

I am writing code to help highlight the file and line number when something crashes in HTML

Example Stacktrace

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.<>c__DisplayClass196_0.<ReadAsync>b__1(Task t) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InvokeRetryable[T](Func`2 moreFunc, TaskCompletionSource`1 source, IDisposable objectToDispose) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at ExampleProjectSystem.API.Services.ReportRepository.SearchCustomerByAdvanceFilters(TableBaseDto filter, String ReportName) in E:\SharedProjects\ExampleProjectAPI\Services\ReportRepository.cs:line 445
```

I'd only want **ReportRepository.cs:line 445** so I can perform change the font/color/css in the HTML when viewing the crash.

Comment: You want to capture everything between the backslash and the text `:line` plus the number after, so `([^\\]+:line \d+)`. https://regex101.com/r/wTkppa/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
([^\s\\]+):line\s+(\d+)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5e%5cs%5c%5c%5d%2b%29%3aline%5cs%2b%28%5cd%2b%29&i=ExampleProjectSystem.API.Services.ReportRepository.SearchCustomerByAdvanceFilters%28TableBaseDto+filter%2c+String+ReportName%29+in+E%3a%5cSharedProjects%5cExampleProjectAPI%5cServices%5cReportRepository.cs%3aline+445). Output:

[image]

*Details*:

- `([^\s\\]+)` - Capturing gropup 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and `\`
- `:line` - a literal text
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/zrGwNd):

```cs
var text = @"ExampleProjectSystem.API.Services.ReportRepository.SearchCustomerByAdvanceFilters(TableBaseDto filter, String ReportName) in E:\SharedProjects\ExampleProjectAPI\Services\ReportRepository.cs:line 445";
var pattern = @"([^\s\\]+):line\s+(\d+)";
var result = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
if (result.Success) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1].Value); // => ReportRepository.cs
    Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[2].Value); // => 445
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\w+\.\w+:line\s\d+` (check this out: https://regexr.com/65d2l)

Explanation:

- First `\w+` matches `ReportRepository`.
- `\.` escapes the dot and matches it.
- `\w+` matches `cs`.
- `:line\s` matches `:line` .
- `\d+` matches 445.